# How to prove that $IJ\subseteq P\implies I\subseteq P \vee J \subseteq P$

Tags: ring-theory, maximal-and-prime-ideals, noncommutative-algebra

I'm having some trouble with the following exercise:

> Let $R$ be a non trivial ring with unity, and let $P\neq 0$ be an ideal of $R$. Prove that if $R/P$ is a prime ring, then for all right Ideals $I,J$ in $R$, we have that $IJ\subseteq P\implies I\subseteq P \text{ or } J \subseteq P$.

Here I use the following definitions: An ideal $P$ of $R$ is prime, if for any ideals $I,J$, we have that $IJ\subseteq P\implies I\subseteq P \vee J \subseteq P$.

$R$ is a prime ring if $(0)$ is a prime ideal.

---

This is what I've tried so far:

Let $I,J$ be right ideals of $R$ such that $IJ\subseteq P$. Then $(IJ)/P \subseteq 0 + P =(0)$. This implies that $(I/P)(J/P)\subseteq 0+P$. The problem now is that $I/P$ and $J/P$ are right Ideals of $R/P$, meaning that we cannot use the fact that $(0)_{R/P}$ is prime.

---

how can I continue and conclude this proof?

Comment: What does $R\vee J$ mean?

Comment: @C.Ding: $\vee$ is the logical connector "or". It would be better written out, but the statement to be proven is "either $I\subseteq P$, or $J\subseteq P$".

Comment: Note that $(IJ)/P$ is not correct: although $IJ$ is an ideal of $R$, it is not an ideal of $R$ *that contains $P$*, so you cannot consider "$(IJ)/P$". The best you can do is consider $(IJ)+P/P$, but this is already known to just be $P/P$. Likewise, you cannot even write $I/P$ or $J/P$. And $(IJ)/P$ is a subset of $R/P$, so you cannot say it is contained in the set $0+P$ which is a subset of $R$, not of $R/P$.

Comment: Hint: by contradiction, suppose $IJ \subseteq P$ but $i \in I \backslash P, j \in J \backslash P$. Then, ...

Answer (score 0):

Consider ideals $RI$ and $RJ$. Since $RIRJ=RIJ\subset RP\subset P$, $(RI/P)(RJ/P)=0$. It follows that $RI/P=0$ or $RJ/P=0$ and hence $I\subset RI\subset P$ or $J\subset RJ\subset P$.

Comment: Do you know whether $P\subseteq RI$? If not, then on what grounds do you write $RI/P$? Same for $RJ$. You should be using $RI+P$ and $RJ+P$.

Comment: @ArturoMagidin I use the following definition: $S/P:=\{[s]\in R/P: s\in S\}$, where $S$ is a subset of $R$, not necessarily contains $P$.

Comment: That should be mentioned. And then you need to prove you get an ideal, as it does not follow from the correspondence theorem. You should work with $RI+P$ instead, and avoid both the nonstandard notation and the need to prove additional stuff. Note that $(RI+P)(RJ+P)\subseteq RIRJ+P\subseteq P+P =P$, so the rest of the arguments carries through after that.

Comment: Could you submit a full proof @ArturoMagidin? I'm having some trouble following your arguments

Comment: @EduardoMagalhães I'm not presenting arguments to follow. I'm pointing out the notation assumes things you haven't proven